# Material UI invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the following template for a blog. But I want to try out Material UI. But when I add the useStyles-Hook I get an invalid hook error. Does anyone know how to implement Material UI without getting an error. Thank you in advance!

This is the error message:
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  title: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export default function Navigation({ categories }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <AppBar position="static">
          <Toolbar>
            <IconButton
              edge="start"
              className={classes.menuButton}
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="menu"
            >
              <MenuIcon />
            </IconButton>
            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
              News
            </Typography>
            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample doesn't contains the MaterialUI parts.

did you try:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
});

export default function Hook() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Hook</Button>;
}
```

https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still get an invalid hook call error